# Apache Camel Chronicle Component [Deprecated]

Tags: java, apache-camel, memory-mapped-files, chronicle, chronicle-queue

Why has this particular component been deprecated?  Is Java moving away from supporting mapped memory?  We have a special use case where this would be nice to have, two applications that should never have been uncoupled and are currently communicating via REST which causes a great deal of latency.  The data is basically big blobs of binary serial data, so to wrap REST around it we first need to encode it and package it in an object, then unmarshal it on the other side and unencode it.

The other options are to use netty (incurs a bit more latency than mapped memory due to TCP/IP), named pipes (not natively supported by Java so need to wrap it in C), or spend the time to rewrite this as one application.

Comment: Why not use Chronicle Map or Queue (both Apache 2.0) to exchange this data over memory mapped files?

Comment: That's what I was aiming for, but I thought maybe using a camel component would be wise.

Comment: There is a plan to support Chronicle Map/Queue in Apache Camel but we had not so much time to do it, any contribution is very welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`camel-chronicle` was deprecated in 2.x and removed in Camel 3.0. It was removed, because the developers of the library [Chronicle-Engine](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Engine), which was used by `camel-chronicle` component, decided to move into private repository. It is now commercial, licensed and closed-source product, which is not compatible with Apache 2 licence.

There was two options:

1. Deprecate and remove component.
2. Keep this component unmaintaned forever with the last release from 2017, which was Apache 2 compatible.

We have decided to remove this component in this vote: https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Should-we-deprecate-camel-chronicle-td5829082.html